# Post a question based on another tex file - Eg. Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: templates, sourcecode

If you modified the Legrand Orange Book template to include other environments, and are getting errors based on the new environment, how do you post your code?

Thanks.

Comment: Often (probably always, if you put in some effort) it is possible to move your modifications from the template file directly into the document preamble (maybe using `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`) if the other template is available (on CTAN would be ideal) your example would be rather self-contained.

Comment: This should be asked on meta not here, but basically remove everything you can while still making the error, and when its down to a few lines, post the example here

Comment: FYI: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book